# i18nexus error on Pages Router for i18next

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, i18next, react-i18next

Even though the translation works fine and configuration worked but i am getting error on build , here's the error "Failed to compile.

./node_modules/i18next/typescript/t.v4.d.ts:189:47
Type error: '?' expected.

187 |     : // otherwise access plain key without adding plural and ordinal suffixes
188 |     Res extends readonly unknown[]

> 189 |     ? Key extends `${infer NKey extends number}`
> |                                               ^
> 190 |       ? Res[NKey]
> 191 |       : never
> 192 |     : Res[Key & keyof Res] " I am unable to resolve it. Please anyone help me here.

i have tried updating the versions of typscript and other i18 libraries but nothing worked.